# Does multi-threading improve performance if there are many requests at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, tomcat

I am working on a Java web application using Spring 3 hosted on Tomcat 7 which needs to handle over 2.5k requests/second. I have a `RequestProcesseor` class to which process every HTTP requests with this method:

```
@Service
public class RequestProcesseor {

    public void processSomething(int value1, int value2) {
        // process something...
        // create and deep copy some object
        // some BigDecimal calculations
        // maybe some webservice calls
    }

}
```

There are over 2.5k requests at the same time and will call `processSomething` method. If I made this class multithreaded. *Will it improve the performance? If yes, why? And how can I prove it?*

The server has a 4-core CPU.

Comment: Wow, a great football player using spring.

Comment: Use servlet 3.0 async support: http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-introducing-servlet-3-async-support/

Comment: I think 2.5k requests / second may call for clustering: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you aren't doing any multithreading explicitly, your application server is implicitly dispatching each request to its own thread, so you already have concurrent load on the CPU.

Concurrent code will only help you if your request processing is CPU-limited, which is very rarely the case. Usually the bottleneck is the database or, more generally, the interface to other back-end subsystems.

If each request is processed by crunching a lot of in-memory data, **and** if the request-per-second load is low, **then** it can pay off to carefully divide the work among *a few* threads, no more than the actual CPU core count.

Therefore, since your server is quite heavily loaded, it will be almost certainly impossible to improve its performance by dispatching work to several threads. Note that it is dangerously easy to *ruin* the performance by multithreading.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that Tomcat is already doing multithreading.

It is not always wise to do multithreading on your own inside an application server or web container.

The application server or web container is already doing the multithreading on the requests.

Please read the documentation and/or source code of Tomcat.

Comment: The web container multithreads the requests, but each request may benefit from further multithreading.

Comment: @BrianAgnew That's right but as I understand he assumes that the given class is single threaded which does not need to be correct. This depends on the application server. Perhaps the single request could be handled faster but that we can only assume.

Answer (score 3):

> Will it improve the performance?

Maybe. You have 2.5k requests a second. If each request took 1s of CPU time and you had one CPU then it wouldn't. If you had 2 CPUs then yes. If each request talked to remote pooled network resources then yes. If each request talked to the same networked resource (i.e. not pooled) then no.

In short, you need to provide more info about what you're doing, and (most usefully) perform a test yourself using your particular environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer: Yes.**

Every time a request comes in, if you are using only 1 thread to execute this method, it means the next request in line will have to wait until the previous one is processed.

If you create a new thread every time a request comes in, you will be handling all the requests as soon as there are resources available on your system. Your threads will be cleaned up after they are finished anyway.

Comment: At 2500 concurrent requests that is a lot of thread creation and destruction overhead. And depending on how long a single request takes to process a lot more threads than cores. I'd recommend using a ThreadPool for this.

Comment: @confusopoly I agree with that if the processing bit is really short. But he hasn't shown his processing code, so I don't know :)

Comment: The question was about making **this class** multithreaded. Request handling **already is** multithreaded.

Answer (score 1):

*The short* answer is: You'll have to measure it yourself.

*A longer* answer is: If you dispatch your work to a single thread in the background and the HTTP request processor waits for completion of that background thread (what else would it do?) you have just added overhead to your application

Please

- measure if it has some impact
- *if* you have positive impact: Inspect the impact that you measure and determine if the added complexity is worth to trade maintainability with performance

Or, more generally:

- Write the code with optimized maintainability
- Stress test the application until it breaks
- If it breaks earlier than you expect it to break:

  - identify the bottleneck (memory, cpu, i/o, others)
  - fix your identified problem #1
  - continue at step 2
- Congratulations. Your application serves the load that you expect *and* the code is in best maintainable state it can be to meet its performance requirements

Answer (score 0):

I have a different view in the case of your tasks here can be run separately.

```
    // process something...
    // create and deep copy some object
    // some BigDecimal calculations
    // maybe some webservice calls
```

Can we run them parallel? If yes, then multi threading should help. You can create multi threads to handle different tasks at the same time to improve the response time. The requirement is these tasks should be independent from each other, or you are about make it worse because of locks.

But you are doing the same thing 2.5k times/second, you probably can consider if cache can be used to optimize the speed.